# How to return from Cypress recursive call

Tags: recursion, command, cypress

I am new to Cypress and trying to write recursive command to dynamically select year from Calender
but my code is stuck with .then function and not returning even after if condition is fulfilled

```
Cypress.Commands.add("selectYear",(yearName:string):any => {

  const currentYear = new Date().getFullYear() 
  getYearNameElement().then(($Year)=>{
   cy.log($Year.text())
   cy.log("Hello")
    if($Year.text()== yearName){
      cy.log(yearName +"year is selected")
      return // **this return not happening**
    }else{
      if(parseInt(yearName) < currentYear){
        getNavigationBackElement().click()
        cy.log("NavigatedBack")
      }else if (parseInt(yearName) > currentYear){
        getNavigationForwardElement().click()
        cy.log("NavigatedForward")
      }
    }   
  }) 
});
```

output of the above code
-->cy.selectYear('2022')
2023
Hello
NavigatedBack
2023
Hello
NavigatedBack
2023
Hello
NavigatedBack
.
.
.
2022
Hello
2022 year is selected [ after this point code should return]
but it continue in **.then** and print
2022
Hello
2022
Hello
.
.
infinite loop

Please suggest how to resolve this